# Maintaining a Nat within a fixed range

Tags: idris

I'd like to have a `Nat` that remains within a fixed range. I would like functions `incr` and `decr` that fail if they are going to push the number outside the range. This seems like it might be a good use case for `Fin`, but I'm not really sure how to make it work. The type signatures might look something like this:

```
- Returns the next value in the ordered finite set.
- Returns Nothing if the input element is the last element in the set. 
incr : Fin n -> Maybe (Fin n)

- Returns the previous value in the ordered finite set.
- Returns Nothing if the input element is the first element in the set.
decr : Fin n -> Maybe (Fin n)
```

The `Nat` will be used to index into a `Vect n`.  How can I implement `incr` and `decr`?  Is `Fin` even the right choice for this?

Comment: E.g. the Coq standard library uses `Fin` for indexing into vectors. See the definition of the `nth` function [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to use some standard Fin↔Nat conversion functions from `Data.Fin`:

```
incr, decr : {n : Nat} -> Fin n -> Maybe (Fin n)
incr {n=n} f = natToFin (succ $ finToNat f) n

decr {n=n} f = case finToNat f of
    Z => Nothing
    S k => natToFin k n
```